# How do you add data to a data extension, through the UI or API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

In the UI, it appears that a Data Extension is an empty table waiting to hold some data.

However, when I try to populate the table using a Query, the Query requires me to select data FROM a Data Extension.

How do I get data into a Data Extension?

Answer (score 1):

A few different paths you can take.  You can use [REST](http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html) to pass in some data:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:SomeKey/rowset
or
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/11954DDF-28A3-4FE8-BF77-646C37506621/rowset

[
    {
        "keys":{
                "Email": "someone@exacttarget.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys": {
                "Email": "someone2@exacttarget.com"
                },
        "values":{
                "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
                "IsActive": true,
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "FollowerCount": 2,
                "LastName": "Smith"
                }
    }
]
```

You can also import a file of data, such as comma delimited or tab delimited.  In the UI, navigate to your DE and choose the Records tab.  Find the Import button above the data grid.

Comment: The query either needs to be executed against an existing Data Extension or a Data View (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)...the resulting data will be sent to a new Data Extension (that needs to be created beforehand) with the correct column headings already in place. The link above will show you some examples you can test with.

Comment: Technically, you can originate data in a DE without a `from` data extension.  I've used it in the past for adding onesies and twosies for testing.  However, it's much easier to save an Excel worksheet as Unicode and import it with the toolbar Import button.